# What word does 'iucunda' modify in this sentence from Cicero?

Tags: classical-latin, adjective, cicero

I am reading a letter fom Cicero to his friend Atticus and can't quite pinpoint exactly how the word iucunda functions thereof:

"Nam mihi omnia, quae iūcunda ex hūmānitāte alterius et mōribus hominī accidere possunt, ex illō accidēbant." It seems like it can belong to either humanitate or omnia.

Comment: Note that if it were an ablative singular, the final vowel would be long.

Comment: I put in the long vowels myself, I left out iucunda since I'm unsure. I took the text from Loeb Classical Library which doesn't incorporate vowel length.

Comment: Also check [Shuckburgh's translation](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.+Att.+1.5&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0008). I think he makes it clearer.

Comment: @cmw I would not recommend this particular translation to clarify the OP's question since an inattentive reader could misidentify "kindly" with _iucunda_. This does not mean, of course, that I consider it a bad translation.

Comment: @Mitomino Good point. It clarifies it for a careful reader, but I do suppose an inattentive one would be led astray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has already been explained, *iūcunda* is neuter nominative plural modifying *quae*, which has *omnia* as its antecedent. And the translation of *omnia, quae iūcunda...accidere possunt* into English would be 'All pleasant things that are able to happen.'

Now, you might ask yourself why *iūcunda* is being translated closely with the *omnia* in the sentence's main clause, even though it doesn't appear in that clause, instead of being translated with *quae* in the relative clause, where it does appear.

Gildersleeve & Lodge, *Latin grammar* §616.3 explains this:

> Adjectives, especially superlatives, are sometimes transferred from the substantive in the principle clause and made to agree with the Relative in the Relative clause.

One of the examples that G&L provides is:

> **Nēminī crēdō, quī largē blandust dīves pauperī**, Pl[autus], *Aul*[*ularia*], 196; *I trust no rich man who is lavishly kind to a poor man.*

In other words, the sentence from Plautus is equivalent to ***Nēminī dīvitī** crēdō, quī largē blandust pauperī*, but *dīvitī* has been moved into the relative clause and made to agree with *quī*. Likewise, your sentence from Cicero is equivalent to *Nam mihi **omnia iūcunda**, quae ex hūmānitāte alterius et mōribus hominī accidere possunt, ex illō accidēbant*.

Comment: The same effect is possible in English: "I trust no one who, being rich, is lavishly kind to a poor man."

Answer (score 4):

*Iucunda* (plural neuter nominative) modifies the relative pronoun *quae* (subject of *accidere possunt*), whose antecedent is *omnia* (subject of *accidebant*). Here is a nice translation by Reginald Foster & Daniel McCarthy that makes it clear that *iucunda* ('pleasant') goes with *omnia* ('all things') and not with *humanitate* ('kindness'):

> 'For all the pleasant things which are able to happen to a person out of the kindness and behavior of another were happening to me from him'. (Ex. from *Ossa Latinitatis Sola Ad Mentem Reginaldi Rationemque*)